# Javascript: Replacing chan-like replies within a string

Tags: javascript, replace, quote, reply

I am here because I need help solving this problem. So I have this string (for example). Oh and obviously the `&gt;&gt;` are displayed as >>.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet &gt;&gt;21, consetetur sadipscin&gt;&gt;22g elitr.

&gt;&gt;11 I agree.

&gt;&gt;61 Lorem ipsumdur. See &gt;&gt;36
```

What I want to do now is: replace the

```
&gt;&gt;INTEGER
```

with the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scroll(INTEGER)">&gt;&gt;INTEGER</a>
```

Comment: try regular expression replace, btw have you tried anything to get solution??

Comment: I am totally cluesless about regular expression replaces, sorry. I'll do some research right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
yourString.replace(/&gt;&gt;[0-9]+/g,'firstPart'+'$&'+'secondPart');
```

Refer [javascript replace method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) for more details.
Where "$&"  , Inserts the matched substring.
So the final code would be :

```
yourString.replace(/&gt;&gt;[0-9]+/g,'<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert($1);">'+'$&'+'<\/a>');
```

Comment: I have modified your code so it replaces all strings. But I cannot get the INTEGER to come up in the replacement. Can you help out?

My code:

`replace(/&gt;&gt;[0-9]+/g, '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert($1);">&gt;&gt;$1<\/a>');`

Answer (score 0):

You just call a **replace** in scroll function.

ej

```
var stringToReplace = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet &gt;&gt;21, consetetur sadipscin&gt;&gt;22g elitr......',
textReplaced = ' your new value here';


function scroll(integer){

   return stringToReplace.replace(new RegExp('&gt;&gt;'+integer,'g'),textReplaced);

}
```